# Handling linked systems

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have many systems that talk to each other and its become a bit of a mess.  e.g system B gets data from system A and System A gets data from System C which also gets data from System B etc etc.  The data is passed around using a variety of methods.  Some of the data is copied across using SQL periodically thus duplicating the data.  Some of the data is pulled using views locally and remotely in real-time.

We want to come up with a better solution.  My plan is to create a central repository that the systems dump and get data from.  Does this sound like a good idea?  What's the best practice for handling data between remote systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like a [data warehouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse)? This is pretty standard as long as you don't want to update the data, and just want to use it for reporting/driving other applications.

You have a variety of options for getting the data in there including linked servers, SSIS packages and replication (if between oracle servers or ms sql servers)

Comment: So say we have an application "system A" which holds contact info and System B needs that data so someone can choose a contact from a drop down list when inputting a form, this would be the way to go.  I was under the impression Data Warehousing was only for OLAP stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can read Microsoft recomendation: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd459147(SQL.100).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd459147%28SQL.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As Martin Booth and Dalex say, if the data is used only for reporting, a datawarehouse is the obvious solution.

If you use the data in transactional systems, there are some other options.

If your system is primarily about data, I'd consider using ETL tools (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) to manage the copying around of data.

If your system is not just about data, you should look at a service-oriented architecture; this is a brilliantly vague term, and can result in many billable consulting hours, so it's worth doing your homework. In general, the idea is to decouple the underlying implementation (views, replication, dump/restore etc.) from the conceptual "services". This might be too big a jump from where you are now - but the principles are useful when design your solution.

Comment: What about something like biztalk to handle the data

Comment: Yep - that's a logical next step, though it does introduce a very large additional piece of infrastructure into your project environment. I'd only do that once you know you need it; you could also look at less sophisticated products like NServiceBus or Mass Transit.